# Stacked bodies, no applied forces, internal forces accelerate the whole system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

A block P of mass $m_{1}$ in on a frictionless horizontal plane and a block Q of mass $m_{2}$ is always on top of P. Initially P and Q are at rest. At time t=0, an initial speed $v_{0}$  is given to P in the rightward direction. Then Q also starts to move. When a time T is passed after P is given an
initial speed, the velocity of P coincides with the velocity of Q. A coefficient
of kinetic friction between P and Q is denoted as µ. Treat the rightward
direction as positive, and the acceleration of gravity is denoted as $g$.
[Diagram](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15XuLzuT2ri8cmIUPKDdxouZvMW6Adoh6/view?usp=drivesdk)
**Find the expression of T using some other suitable quantities.**

This is a question of the [MEXT scholarships selection test of physics 2016](https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/en/planning/scholarship/application/examination/index.html)

Can you please help me out with the solution, tried to use kinematic equations but I'm missing out something.

Comment: To give P its initial velocity without moving Q, P would have to be hit with a very brief impulse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the diagram, P has mass M and Q has mass m.  Then the final velocity:
V = $v_o$ - (μmg/M)T = 0 + (μmg/m)T.  Solve for T.

Comment: Thanks bro, I had trouble because I didn't take Q initial velocity as 0. Couldn't interpret that